# The behavior of the "this" keyword in abstract classes and generics

Tags: java, generics, this, abstract-class

## Consider the following classes

#### Reinventing the wheel as far as serialization goes, I know:

```
abstract class AnimalSerializer<E extends Animal> {
    /**
     * The type E (which extends Animal) is important here. 
     * I want to be able to write data that is specific to a subclass of an animal.
     */
    abstract void writeAnimal(E animal);
    abstract Animal readAnimal();
}

abstract class Animal {
    AnimalSerializer<? extends Animal> serializer;

    Animal(AnimalSerializer<? extends Animal> speciesSerializer) {
        serializer = speciesSerializer;
    }

    void writeAnimalToFile() {
        // This line fails to compile
        serializer.writeAnimal(this);
    }
}
```

#### These classes demonstrate the use of this pattern:

```
class DogSerializer extends AnimalSerializer<Dog> {

    @Override
    void writeAnimal(Dog animal) {
        // Write the stuff that is specific to the dog
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    Animal readAnimal() {
        // Read the stuff specific to the dog, instantiate it, and cast it as an animal.
        // ...
        return null;
    }  
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    String dogTag = "Data specific to dog.";

    Dog() {
        super(new DogSerializer());
    }
}
```

My question pertains to the line that failed to compile (`serializer.writeAnimal(this)`). I had to pull up the language specification for the first time to learn more about the `this` keyword, but I think the issue is that the "this" keyword is of the type `Animal`, and the bounded wildcard generic `<? extends Animal>` only supports types that are subclasses of Animal, not the `Animal` type itself.

I would argue that the compiler should know that the type of the `this` keyword **must** be an object that extends Animal, given that Animal cannot be instantiated, and the `this` keyword is only applicable to objects that have been.

Is there a reason why the compiler cannot know this? My guess is that there is a case that explains why the `this` keyword cannot be guaranteed to be a subclass of Animal.

Furthermore, is this pattern fundamentally flawed as a result?

Comment: `this` means *the instantiated instance* (although the *type of the expression* of `this` is that of the class it appears in). An abstract class *must* be instantiated (via a concrete type) before use ..

Comment: @user2864740 No. First, the problem is because the type is really not match. Second, `this` never means *instantiated instance*.

Comment: @DeanXu Do explain the latter.

Comment: @user2864740 Your first sentence is correct. The second sentence does not make sense: The `this` keyword always refers to the current instance we are in (which is what @DeanXu meant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `serializer` generic type is `? extends Animal`. Your `this` type is `Animal`, which also can be considered as `? extends Animal`. But these two `?` are different types. There is no constraint to let the compiler know they are same type.

For example, I write a `Cat` class

```
class Cat extends Animal {
  Cat(){
    super(new DogSerializer()); // this is ok for your generic
  }
}
```

This is why the compiler gives you an error.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Dean said:
You can make `Animal` generic: `Animal<S extends Animal>`
Then the serializer becomes `AnimalSerializer<S> serializer`. Now it references a "known" subclass of Animal.
And the extends becomes `Dog extends Animal<Dog>`. Unfortunately, there is no way to prevent `Cat extends Animal<Dog>`.

You still have to cast in the offending line: `serializer.writeAnimal((S)this);`
But now it is possible to do that because you know what class to cast to.

This is the downside of `?` in generics.